How to modify what is shown as website preview in whatsapp chat - description
I have the following setup in my _quarto.yml file
project:
  type: website

website:
  title: "Title"
  site-url: "https://example.com/"
  description: "This is where I would think it shows up in whatsapp"
  navbar:
    left:
  ## removed index from navbar 
      - about.qmd

format:
  html:
    theme: cosmo
    css: styles.css
    toc: true

index.qmd is plain and simply:
---
title: "index title"
---

I have deployed this test website on netlify.
When sending a website via whatsapp, it presents a preview containing a title and an apparently optional description (see screenshot example: bbc.com).

I essentially have two questions, but they are likely strongly related.
1) How do I modify the title shown (in my case: I do not want to show "Index title" but something else, without however modifying the title of the index page.
2) How do I add a description to my project which whatsapp recognises as such? I expected this to be the "description" key which I added in the yml file. But it clearly isn't.
To be fair, I don't really care so much about this whatsapp feature, but I feel that this is of some importance for any search engines so I'd rather understand how to modify this.
